# go conditional compilation problem

Tags: build, compiler-construction, go

I have two files, production_constants.go and local_constants.go in the same package.

At the top of each I have:

```
// +build production

package receivers
```

and

```
// +build local

package receivers
```

When I compile with either tag ("go install -tags local", for example)  The same constants are used for either tag (ie the compile tags aren't respected).  If I remove the build headers, weirdly everything still compiles and the same constants are used.  Only when I remove all of the space above the package declaration ("package receivers") do I receive the "*_* redeclared in this block".

I'm confused as I think I've done exactly what the documentation has indicated for a conditionally built package.  Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if this is a compilation issue (as mentioned [in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/zFE2wk97Rrs)) with:

```
go clean -i receivers
# or
go install -a -tags local
```

By forcing a full recompilation of every files, the tags should work.